# import gensim imports a file in an active module, not the root site-packages folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim

I'm running Anaconda Python 2.7 on Windows. I've installed gensim and pyLDAvis to do some topic modeling. (Note installing pyLDAvis on python 2.7 in windows is a little tricky as you have to make sure you are not using scikit-bio which doesn't appear to compile on Windows 2.7... I think I have a workaround for this, but I can't try it because of reasons to be outlined below!)

So I got pyLDAvis to install. However when running, it seems to have a problem with an import statement.

pyLDAvis is installed in this folder....

```
C:\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\pyLDAvis-1.3.2-py2.7.egg\pyLDAvis
```

`sys.path` returns this:

```
['',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\pyldavis-1.3.2-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\joblib-0.9.3-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\python27.zip',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\DLLs',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\lib-tk',
'C:\\Anaconda2',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\Library\\bin',
'c:\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',
'c:\\anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-18.4-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptography-1.0.2-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
'C:\\Anaconda2\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions']
```

What is happening is that when I try to run `pyLDAvis`, the library calls `import gensim`. However, `gensim` is both a folder in the `site-packages` and a file (`gensim.py`) inside `pyLDAvis`.

So when python tries to `import gensim` inside the `pyLDAvis` module, it imports the `gensim.py` file within the `pyLDAvis` module, not the ``gensim`folder inside`site-packages`.

How do I go about fixing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File an issue report on [pyLDAvis's GitHub](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/issues). It looks like a [recent change](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis/commit/848b247b77bb24b1e674aa0cf7c0d5f9b4f26a9d) broke Python 2 compatibility by assuming Python 3 absolute import behavior for `import gensim`.

In the meantime, I believe the bug isn't present in the 1.3.1 release, so you could use that. Alternatively, you could edit `pyLDAvis/gensim.py` and add `from __future__ import absolute_import` at the top. That'd *probably* work as a temporary fix, but I didn't try it.

Comment: You are amazing. `from __future__ import absolute_import` worked like a charm!